# Is there a way to preserve modified date from a directory if I remove a file from it?

Tags: uninstall, date

I'm kind new on Linux world and trying do some stuff, like creating that classic bash example to remove files older than X days. I was able to do that, but there is one think I can't solve, when the bash remove some files from the directory, he remove some older files then update the directory last change, so in the next time bash is executed and remove the rest of files, it won't remove the directory in question in the end, because the directory time have been update to the last time the rm command was executed.

Here's a image from what I mean, the directories marked had all its old files inside removed but the directory itself was not removed because its date updated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a file you are changing the containing directory so it is normal that the change time of the directory shows the current time afterwards.

You may 'restore' the change time with the `touch` command.